# bluebird - Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Error]

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

When throwing an exception from the `.then` function of a bluebird promise, the following warning message appears: `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Error]`.

This happens when running tests using:

- node 9.6.1
- bluebird 3.5.3
- karma 2.0.0
- chai 4.2.0
- chai-as-promised 7.1.1

Here is a small code sample that throws an Error instance following the resolution of a promise, using node's implementation and bluebird's:

```
import chai from 'chai'
import bluebird from 'bluebird'
import promised from 'chai-as-promised'
const { expect } = chai.use(promised)

describe('warning when promise throws', () => {
  const dummyErrorMessage = 'dummy error message'

  async function throws (p) {
    await p.resolve().then(() => {
      throw new Error(dummyErrorMessage)
    })
  }

  describe('throws', () => {
    it('with vanilla promise', async () => {
      await expect(throws(Promise))
        .to.be.rejectedWith(Error, dummyErrorMessage)
    })

    it('with bluebird promise', async () => {
      await expect(throws(bluebird))
        .to.be.rejectedWith(Error, dummyErrorMessage)
    })
  })
})
```

Which outputs:

```
  warning when promise throws
    throws
      ✓ with vanilla promise
WARN LOG: 'Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error: [object Error]'
      ✓ with bluebird promise
```

The bluebird documentation offers potential explanations about that warning but it doesn't seem to fit (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-rejected-with-a-non-error).

Could anyone explain if this is expected and why, please?

Comment: Can you include the actual output of the error i.e. [object Error] ? Shouldn't you be trying to catch the errors with a .catch in the 'throws' function?

Comment: Having your test file and having it run with `mocha --require babel-core/register` I get no warning at all.

Comment: Wow, that’s a frustrating error - sorry for this! This usually happens when there are errors between realms (iframes or vms in Node) or there are objects called literally Error that are not actual errors. Can you make a repo reproducing this in GitHub?

Comment: Here you go @BenjaminGruenbaum: https://github.com/jderrough/warning-when-promise-throws